# How to correctly display the time in the H:M:S format with std::put_time and std::chrono

Tags: c++

I'm trying to measure the time of the function with std::chrono. But the time does not output correctly. adds 3 hours for some reason.

my code

```
auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { Sleep(1000); }

auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

const std::time_t total = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - begin).count();

std::stringstream ssTotal;

ssTotal << std::put_time(std::localtime(&total), "%H:%M:%S");
```

Output Total: 03:00:05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `std::time_t` is intended for a time point not a duration, and when you then pass it through `std::localtime` it tries to take your local timezone into account.

The "correct" answer is to stick to durations all the way through, but AFAIK the nice formatting and printing stuff for that is a C++20 feature that isn't widely implemented yet.

A quick workaround is to use `std::gmtime` instead of `std::localtime`, as that adjusts to the +0 timezone.

Comment: Yes, indeed, my mistake was that I used the local time. Everything works correctly with std::gmtime. Thanks for the quick response.